# How to switch to edit mode vector layers, in pyqt application based on qgis?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I do QGIS based application, I need to implement the ability to modify the geometry of vector layers in manual mode (editing nodes), how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

### QGIS Vector Layer Class

You will need to become familiar with layer attributes and features. The [QGIS Vector Layer Class Reference](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) will be a good source of information.

### Basic Workflow

The basic workflow will be to:

1. Select the layer via the `QgsVectorLayer` class
2. Get some or all features in the layer with the [getFeatures()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a412ac9a3563e542485927bde03397962)
3. Work with the feature geometry (with [insertVertex()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a30e3cce740eee93224f8892bc145fea8), [moveVertex()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aedd7741baf73478a6887426ccc159e3a), [deleteVertex()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a46a4bb3531417d6a2ffff22b7e83554a), etc.

### Example

```
# Load a vector layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/layer.shp',"Legend Name", "ogr")

# E.g. Set up a rectangle for use as a bounding box query
filter_rectangle = QgsRectangle(-100, 50, -130, 60)   

# Create a feature request object
feature_query = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(filter_rectangle)

# Get a set of features for manipulation, using the feature query object
features = layer.getFeatures(feature_query)

# You can now iterate through the features
for feature in features:
    # Do something
```

### Further Reading

The above code was adapted from the [PyQGIS Programmer's Guide](https://locatepress.com/ppg).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Digitizing Tools plugin. Once enabled, select Toggle Editing then you can play around with editing geometries, shapes etc with the available functions.